# How to set object property to null in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am uploading a list of Objects to MySQL. 
Some of the objects do not contain the same number of variables. For example

```
Objectt1 {
property1
property 2
}

Objectt2 {
property1
property2
property3
}

Objectt3 {
property1
}
```

My problem is that Object3 in mysql is being given a property2 and property3 instead of NULL. the value is being taken from the Object2. How can I make object 3's propery2 and property3 null? The php code is as follows: (I think I understand why it does this, because the variable is isset already in a previous run of the loop. But I don't know how to fix it.)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require 'connection.php';
    uploadstart();
}

function uploadstart() {
    global $connect; 

    $json = $_POST["objectlist"];

    //Remove Slashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $json = stripslashes($json);
    }

    $createworkoutquery = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO objectTable 
                                                (id, prop1, prop2, prop3) 
                                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $createworkoutquery->bind_param("ssss", $ID, $prop1, $prop2, $prop3) ;
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    //Util arrays to create response JSON
    $a=array();
    $b=array();

    // loop through the array
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // get the list details
        $ID = $row["id"];    
        $prop1 = $row["prop1"];

        if (isset($row["prpop2"])) {
            $prop2 = $row["prop2"];
        }

        if (isset($row["prop3"])) {
            $prop3 = $row["prop3"];
        }


        // execute insert query
        $result = $createworkoutquery->execute();

        //if insert successful.. plug yes and woid else plug no
        if($result){
            $b["id"] = $ID;
            $b["status"] = 'yes';
            array_push($a,$b);
        } else {
            $b["id"] = $ID;
            $b["status"] = 'no';
            array_push($a,$b);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($a);

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);

}
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If you have a lot of properties, and you expect a lot of null values, why not restructure your table so that it allows you to have variable properties? Such as, `id | object_id | property_name | property_value`?

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` has been hard-coded to return `false` for some years now. Unless you're on a really old server you should be able to safely remove it. Also, is your ID a string? "ssss" suggests it is.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for pointing those out. I've been looking at some old tutorials from a bunch of sites so their codes aren't realy as updated.  My Id is being plugged into an integer column, will i run into future problems if i  retain it as s?

Comment: You could if someone tries mucking with your database. PHP won't stop someone from trying to insert non-numeric data. Probably it's nothing but better to do things right. PHP has been through a lot of changes, and started out very poorly. You should be using PHP 7, and paying very close attention to dates on articles. Anything before about 2012 should be ignored unless you can corroborate it with a newer source.

Comment: @miken32 cool. I'll keep that in mind. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `null` to the missing properties on each iteration so the previous value doesn't get bound to the query:

```
foreach($data as $row){
    $ID = $row['id'];
    $prop1 = isset($row['prop1'])? $row['prop1']: null;
    $prop2 = isset($row['prop2'])? $row['prop2']: null;
    $prop3 = isset($row['prop3'])? $row['prop3']: null;

    $result = $createworkoutquery->execute();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds +1

Comment: @RiggsFolly That doesn't happen often

Comment: It does to me, or do you mean the +1

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean me beating you to the punch.

Comment: Let's delete the question then

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is a mispelling  prpop2

```
if (isset($row["prpop2"])) {
    $prop2 = $row["prop2"];
}
```